# If $\lambda(f_n^{-1}(U))$ converges for all measurable sets $U,$ does $\{f_n\}$ have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^1_{[0,1]}([0,1])$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1].$ If $\{ \lambda(f_n^{-1}(U)) \}$ is a convergent sequence for all measurable sets $U,$ does $\{f_n\}$ have a convergent subsequence in $L^1$?

My attempt: let $f(U) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda(f_n^{-1}(U)),$ then it is easy to check $f$ is a measure on $[0,1].$ If $f_n \to g,$ we need $\mu(g^{-1}(U)) = f(U)$ for all $U.$ However, this equation only determines $g$ up to a measure preserving bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$ so I'm not sure what the limit should be. Without knowing what the limit should be, how do I prove convergence? Perhaps we can show $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy instead and use the completeness of $L^1,$ but I'm not sure how to do that either.

We can't prove convergence directly since $f_{2n} = \chi_{[1/2, 1]}, f_{2n+1} = \chi_{[0,1/2]}$ is a counterexample, and I only need a subsequence. Any ideas?

Comment: The below counterexample also shows it’s not guaranteed there is a subsequence which is convergent in measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence is a counterexample: $f_n = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Let $U$ be measurable. Since
$$
\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U)) =\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U \cap (-\infty,1))) + \lambda( f_n^{-1}(U \cap [1,+\infty))) 
$$
we can discuss the cases $U \subset (-\infty,1)$ and $U \subset [1,+\infty)$
separately.

If $U \subset (-\infty,1)$ and $0\in U$ then $\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U)) = 1-\frac1n\to 1$. If $0\not\in U$ then $\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U)) =0$.

If $U \subset [1,+\infty)$ then $\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U))  \le \frac1n \to0$.

So $\lambda( f_n^{-1}(U))$ is convergent for all measurable subsets $U$, but $(f_n)$ does not converge in $L^1$ and does not have a converging subsequence. In particular $\|f_n -f_m\|_{L^1} \ge 1$ for $m\ne n$.

Comment: I think they asked if $(f_n)$ admits an $L^1$-convergent subsequence but this is not true either

Comment: Yes, it is easy to see that it cannot contain a subsequence that is Cauchy.